# VB.NET If ElseIf issue in Timer

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, timer

I was trying to run 3 timer using a single button and each click 1 timer will run. It was running smooth in the second timer but on the 3rd click the 3rd timer didnt run. Can anyone help me with this one?

Here's my code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
            Timer1.Start()
        ElseIf Timer1.Enabled = True Then
            Timer2.Start()
        ElseIf Timer1.Enabled = True And
            Timer2.Enabled = true Then
            Timer3.Start()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1
        If Label1.Text = 60 Then
            Label1.Text = 0
            Label2.Text += 1
        ElseIf Label2.Text = 60 Then
            Label2.Text = 0
            Label3.Text += 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Label6.Text = Label6.Text + 1
        If Label6.Text = 60 Then
            Label6.Text = 0
            Label5.Text += 1
        ElseIf Label5.Text = 60 Then
            Label5.Text = 0
            Label4.Text += 1
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
        Label12.Text = Label12.Text + 1
        If Label12.Text = 60 Then
            Label12.Text = 0
            Label11.Text += 1
        ElseIf Label11.Text = 60 Then
            Label11.Text = 0
            Label10.Text += 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ouch, watch your keyboard mate! Turning off CAPS lock is just tap away.

Comment: Does not look C# to me. Please clarify how C# is related to your problem.

Comment: During 3rd click the code would again fire the `Timer2.Enabled` line, so you should re-arrange the `IF` condition up-side down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for your second ElseIf and the first part of the third ElseIf is the same, meaning the third one never executes the code inside it, because it always falls into the second condition.

It would make your code more simple to hold a variable to keep track of which timer you need to start. Also if you use a case statement, then addig more timers is a simple task.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'declare a static variable which keeps its value
        Static whichTimer As Integer = 0
        'every time the button is clicked increment the value
        whichTimer += 1

        'now start the appropriate timer
        Select Case whichTimer
            Case 1
                Timer1.Start()
            Case 2
                Timer2.Start()
            Case 3
                Timer3.Start()
            Case Else
                'don't care
        End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is on the scope, Here if one condition is found inside (IF, ELSE IF, ELSE IF, ELSE ) statement then the code will enter on that scope and will not check other conditions. For example,

```
IF (CONDITION)
..some code
ELSE IF(CONDITION) // if this condition is found true, then compiler will not check other condtion
..some code // this code will be executed only
ELSE IF(CONDITION)
..some code
ELSE
..some code
```

At first ensure all are enabled true or false and Change your code as below:

```
     If Timer1.Enabled = False And Timer2.Enabled = False And  Timer3.Enabled=False Then
            Timer1.Start()
     End If
     If Timer1.Enabled = True And Timer2.Enabled = False And  Timer3.Enabled=False Then
            Timer2.Start()
     End If
     If Timer1.Enabled = True And Timer2.Enabled=True And Timer3.Enabled=False Then
            Timer3.Start()
     End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between If and ElseIf

If the First Condition matches it would not go to the next condition to check so in this scenario this code has to be replaced like this

```
If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
    Timer1.Start()
End If

If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
    Timer2.Start()
End If  

If Timer1.Enabled = True And Timer2.Enabled = true Then
    Timer3.Start()
End If
```

**Edit**

As per your comment you can do something like this

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ClickCount as Integer 
    ClickCount = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ClickCount = ClickCount + 1
        If Timer1.Enabled = False and ClickCount = 1 Then
            Timer1.Start()
        ElseIf Timer1.Enabled = True and ClickCount = 2 Then
            Timer2.Start()
        ElseIf Timer1.Enabled = True And Timer2.Enabled = true and ClickCount = 3  Then
            Timer3.Start()
            ClickCount = 0;
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: i tried doing that a while ago and when i click the button all 3 timer will run simultaneously.

Comment: Okay you want when you click first time it run the First Timer and then next Click it runs the second one and on the third time it runs the third one.. Is it ??

Answer (score 1):

Your code never gets to the 2nd `ElseIf`. Since the third time you click the button the statement `Timer1.Enabled = True` is still true it enters that section of code. That makes the section to enable the third timer unreachable.

What you're really looking for:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If Timer1.Enabled = True And Timer2.Enabled = True Then
            Timer3.Start()
        ElseIf Timer1.Enabled = True Then
            Timer2.Start()
        Else 
            Timer1.Start()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1
        If Label1.Text = 60 Then
            Label1.Text = 0
            Label2.Text += 1
        ElseIf Label2.Text = 60 Then
            Label2.Text = 0
            Label3.Text += 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

        Label6.Text = Label6.Text + 1
        If Label6.Text = 60 Then
            Label6.Text = 0
            Label5.Text += 1
        ElseIf Label5.Text = 60 Then
            Label5.Text = 0
            Label4.Text += 1
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick

        Label12.Text = Label12.Text + 1
        If Label12.Text = 60 Then
            Label12.Text = 0
            Label11.Text += 1
        ElseIf Label11.Text = 60 Then
            Label11.Text = 0
            Label10.Text += 1
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```